# JQuery .not(find()) or - can it be used?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div class="profileRowHeader"><!-- div 1 -->
    <div class="folderIcon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-close"></i>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="profileRowHeader"><!-- div 2 -->
    <div class="folderIcon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="profileRowHeader"><!-- div 3 -->
    <div class="folderIcon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click element with class `.profileRowHeader`, it does some stuff and changes the icon folder from closed to open. As in middle div above.

```
$this.find(".folderIcon").toggleClass('glyphicon-folder-open glyphicon-folder-close');
```

Works great. Now, if I click on div 3 above, div 2 still has icon folder-open, so to combat this i close all the folder icons whenever any `profileHeaderRow` is clicked.

```
$(".folderIcon").removeClass('glyphicon-folder-open').addClass('glyphicon-folder-close');
```

Problem of course is that i'm using toggleClass, so the icon within the div i'm clicking will go to closed, then will toggle itself open again.

So, can I somehow find the class `folderIcon` within the div I clicked and not apply the class change to it. Hope that makes sense.

This is what I'm trying but simply does not work:

```
$(".folderIcon").not(find(".folderIcon")).removeClass('glyphicon-folder-open').removeClass('greenDragBg').addClass('glyphicon-folder-close');
```

Full code as it is:

```
$('.profileRowHeader').click(function() {

        $(".folderIcon").not(find(".folderIcon")).removeClass('glyphicon-folder-open').addClass('glyphicon-folder-close');

        $this.find(".folderIcon").toggleClass('glyphicon-folder-open glyphicon-folder-close');

    });
```

**Summary:** I have x number of divs with class `profileRowHeader` within each of them is a folder icon, all closed... when I click any of the divs with class `profileRowHeader` I want that icon to become open, the rest are closed. When I click that div again, it changes to closed icon. However, if it is left open and another div is clicked it should close the open one, and the new folder icon within the new `profileRowHeader` becomes open.

Hope that's a bit clearer

Comment: Can you add your exact requirements to your OP. It's really unclear what you are expecting to happen when an item is clicked.

Comment: BTW your JS toggles classes on the `<i>`s while the JS toggles them on `.folderIcon`s, also `$this` hasn't been defined. I assume it's a copy-paste mistake. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté it is defined I just forgot to add in here when i took a bunch of other stuff out to save reading useless info - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) elements inside the clicked element:

```
$(".folderIcon").not( $(this).find(".folderIcon") ) //...
```

Or a slightly shorter version setting a [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) for the selector:

```
$(".folderIcon").not( $(".folderIcon", this) ) //...
```

Comment: That's it! I was on the right lines just syntax error, awesome thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.profileRowHeader').click(function () {
    // reset state of all icons back to closed
    $('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-folder-open').addClass('glyphicon-folder-close');    

    $('.glyphicon').find(':first').toggleClass('glyphicon-folder-close glyphicon-folder-open');
});
```